# Autohotkey: Set input length to 'any'

Tags: autohotkey

I am scanning 4 barcodes that sends as N123P123Q12V123456 with different length on the numbers. When I scan it splits the string correct at the characters, and outputs it with the enter as it should. But I can't press any key after the scan, let's say that I want to write something manually - it does not work with this code.

I would also like to add F1, delay, F4 at the end of the string (after V-string). Is it just Send {F1} ?

```
Loop
{

Input, OutputVar, L26 M

 if (RegExMatch(OutputVar, "iO)([A-Z]\d+)([A-Z]\d+)([A-Z]\d+)([A-Z]\d+)", Output))
  for k,v in % StrSplit(RegExReplace(OutputVar,"(?<=\d)[A-Z]\d+","|$0"),"|") {
  send, % v "{Enter}"
  Sleep, 500
 }

}
```

Comment: You're not able to type after it, because you're looping and using `Input`. So all your input is consumed by the `Input`. Can you maybe explain a bit better what sort of behavior you're after so I can write an answer for that?

Comment: I am scanning 350 times a day, and once in a while I need to use the keyboard when the scanning doesnt work. Then I need a way to exit the scan mode and enter "keyboard" mode. I also need a way to scan different lengths, now it only works with 26-digits. But I only want one scan/unit, so I need a way to set scan mode without have to do it every time I scan. Thank you!

Comment: I found a code that was adapted for scanners, and it seems like he had written a code that identified it as a scan-code by checking if the time between the inputs where below 60ms. I just need a way to be able to scan different lengths of codes (not input L26) and still be able to do inputs with the keyboard when needed. Would appreciate very much if you could help!

Comment: Wait, so what does scanning do? It makes your computer *type* those characters? Interesting. Could you imagine just having a text input box pop up and direct the output of the scanning there? Would be pretty easy at least.

Comment: Today I am scanning 4 barcodes with different data. Part number, quantity and so on. After that a barcode that send F1 and one F4 to store the data in the software. I want everything in one scan, and the scanner had a function where it scans all data in one click. So now I need to scan this long string, split it at N, P, Q, V characters and send each string with an enter in tne end to make the program place each string in the right field.